# Why does my nested cocoon form not save the data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm new to ruby on rails and I am desperately trying to get nested forms to actually work.  So I have created a simple little app to try to make it work using cocoon.

the idea is to:

1. Create a nested "question" that is always assigned to a "section"
2. When creating the "section", the nested "questions" should be able to be added and associated with the section

Currently I am able to see the fields for the question, enter in my data, but when I click "submit".  The questions are not saved to the database.  I am not sure why, and I am not sure how to add them,

So...  here's some code to peruse:

My section form partial:

```
%h2 Sections
= semantic_form_for @section do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :title

    %hr
    - @section.printQuestions @section
    %hr

    %h3 Questions
    #questions
    = f.semantic_fields_for :questions do |question|
      = render 'question_fields', :f => question
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add question', f, :questions, :data => {"association-insertion-method" => "after" }
      %p 
    %input{type: 'submit', value: 'Submit'}
```

-- when submit is clicked, the section is saved but the newly made questions are not saved

the partial for "questions" found within the directory for sections:

```
.question_fields
  = f.inputs do
    %p
      = f.label :question_text
      %br
      = f.text_area :question_text, :rows => 2, :cols => 40
    %p
      = f.label :answer_text
      %br
      = f.text_area :answer_text, :rows => 3, :cols => 60
    = f.input :section_id, input_html: { readonly: true }
    = link_to_remove_association "remove question", f
```

model permissions:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
end


class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    ## the rest is auto-generated
end


class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_section, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def section_params
    params.require(:section).permit(:id, :title, :body, :good_opinion, :image_file_name, :questions_attributes [:id, :question_text, :answer_text, :section_id, :_destroy])
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  end
end
```

output when the code is run:

```
Started PATCH "/sections/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-25 00:01:24 -0400
Processing by SectionsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"x6rDCAMjUrdLCieWPOtwsKvqNrVVkGjv6fuZYwmJRSY=", "section"=>{"id"=>"5", "title"=>"question text", "i
mage_file_name"=>"image.png", "good_opinion"=>"0", "body"=>"body text", "questions_attributes"=>{"1395720076660"=>{"question_text"=>"qqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
 "answer_text"=>"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "section_id"=>"5", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "id"=>"5"}
  ←[1m←[35mSection Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
Unpermitted parameters: id, questions_attributes
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http:5
Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Using Rails 4? You may not be permitting the right keys in your controller, to allow the values to get to your model.

Comment: I am using ruby 4.  What do you mean the "right keys"?

Comment: in my section controller I have the following, which is what I think you mean by "keys"           def section_params
    params.require(:section).permit(:title, questions_attributes: [:id, :question_text, :answer_text, :section_id, :_destroy])
  end

Comment: can you add your controller code to the question? With some logs from what happens when you submit the form?

Comment: added the output to the form

Comment: The arguments passed to `permit` are not valid - specifically, the part that goes `:questions_attributes [:id...` is invalid. It should be `questions_attributes: [:id...`.